# h:selectOneRadio HTML output for jsf 1.1 vs 2.0

Tags: java, html, css, jsf-2

For a selectOneRadio code like blow:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.selectedItem}" enabledClass="selectOneRadio" disabledClass="selectOneRadio">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{myBean.item.label}" itemValue="#{myBean.item.code}"/>   
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

JSF 1.1 seems to be generating the HTML output like below:

```
...
<td><label><input type="radio" ...>text text text text ...... </label></td>
...
```

But in JSF 2.0, it seems to be generating the HTML output like below:

```
...
<td><input type="radio" ...><label>text text text text ...... </label></td>
...
```

In JSF 1.1, I use css style like below to align the long label text that runs over more one line.  But this css style does not seems to be working JSF 2.0 HTML output.

```
.selectOneRadio 
{ display:block;
  text-indent: -25px;
  margin-left: 22px;
}
```

Is there something I can do to make JSF 2.0 generate the output like JSF 1.1 or is there a CSS that will work for the JSF 2.0 output?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle to see if someone can help me with the css solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8j7dK/.  Basically I need the label to be at the same line as the radio button.  If I remove the display:inline-block, the 2 line of the label does not align with the first line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by doing this:

```
.selectOneRadio input { 
    vertical-align: top;
}

.selectOneRadioLabel {
    width: 120px;  /* width has to set at the label.  It won't work if set at table label */
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.selectedItem}" style="selectOneRadio" enabledClass="selectOneRadioLabel" disabledClass="selectOneRadioLabel">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{myBean.item.label}" itemValue="#{myBean.item.code}"/>   
</h:selectOneRadio>
```